# Unmet peer dependency after fresh install and deletion of both node_modules and package.json

Tags: node.js, npm

NPM seems to either not be recognizing or not be installing the packages listed in my package.json. I keep getting warnings which are preventing my build from passing which is a large issue. specifically:

> npm WARN react-datepicker@0.49.0 requires a peer of react@^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
>   npm WARN react-datepicker@0.49.0 requires a peer of react-dom@^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
>   npm WARN react-modal@2.4.1 requires a peer of react@^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
>   npm WARN react-modal@2.4.1 requires a peer of react-dom@^0.14.0 || ^15.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

This warning is confusing for me considering my react dependency is 16.5.0, well beyond ^14.0 or ^15.0. Everything I have looked up has said to delete node_modules and package.json.lock then run npm install but this does not seem to solve the problem or change anything really. Any help would be much appreciated.

here is a copy of my package.json

`{
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "proxy": "http://localhost:3001",
  "devDependencies": {
    "axios-mock-adapter": "^1.13.1",
    "enzyme": "^3.1.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.0.1",
    "husky": "^0.13.4",
    "lint-staged": "^3.6.1",
    "node-sass-chokidar": "0.0.3",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.0.2",
    "prettier": "^1.10.2",
    "react-scripts": "^1.1.4",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.0.0",
    "redux-mock-store": "^1.5.1",
    "redux-testkit": "^1.0.6"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.16.2",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "big.js": "^5.0.3",
    "class-names": "^1.0.0",
    "create-app": "^0.6.0",
    "d3": "^5.5.0",
    "d3-array": "^1.2.1",
    "d3-scale": "^1.0.6",
    "debounce": "^1.0.2",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "jest-enzyme": "^4.0.1",
    "leaflet": "^1.0.3",
    "lodash": "^4.17.10",
    "lodash.throttle": "^4.1.1",
    "mixpanel-browser": "^2.13.0",
    "moment": "^2.18.1",
    "mousetrap": "^1.6.1",
    "numeral": "^2.0.6",
    "polyline-encoded": "^0.0.8",
    "prop-types": "^15.5.10",
    "query-string": "^5.0.0",
    "raven-js": "^3.17.0",
    "rc-trigger": "^1.11.2",
    "react": "^16.5.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.32.0",
    "react-countup": "^2.1.1",
    "react-custom-scrollbars": "^4.1.2",
    "react-datepicker": "^0.49.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.5.0",
    "react-fontawesome": "^1.6.1",
    "react-gravatar": "^2.6.3",
    "react-leaflet": "^1.3.0",
    "react-list": "^0.8.6",
    "react-markdown": "^2.5.1",
    "react-modal": "^2.3.2",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.5",
    "react-router": "^4.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-slider": "^0.8.0",
    "react-sortable-hoc": "^0.6.5",
    "react-transition-group": "1.x",
    "redux": "^3.6.0",
    "redux-form": "^7.0.0",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
    "reselect": "^3.0.1",
    "yarn": "^1.3.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "yarn run build-css && react-scripts build",
    "build-css": "npm rebuild node-sass && node-sass-chokidar --include-path ./src --include-path ./node_modules ./src/ -o ./src/",
    "deploy": "./deploy.sh",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "precommit": "lint-staged",
    "start": "npm-run-all -p watch-css start-js",
    "start-js": "react-scripts start",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "watch-css": "yarn run build-css && node-sass-chokidar --include-path ./src --include-path ./node_modules ./src/ -o ./src/ --watch --recursive"
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "*.js": [
      "prettier --single-quote --write",
      "git add",
      "prettier --write"
    ]
  }
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This warning is confusing for me considering my react dependency is 16.5.0, well beyond ^14.0 or ^15.0.

`^15.0.0` means anything from `15.0.0` up to (but not including) `16.0.0`.

So `16.5.0` is actually too new.